# Speeding up mySQL SPATIAL select based on distance to coordinates

Tags: mysql, spatial

I am trying to move our site over from using a Lat/Lng field (CHAR), when doing distance. This is how we currently do it:

```
SELECT ID,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.35462) ) * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Longitude ) - radians(4.88227) ) + sin( radians(52.35462) ) * sin( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM glinks_Links
WHERE
    (
    ((Latitude BETWEEN (52.35462 - 40/69.0) AND (52.35462 + 40/69.0)) )
    AND
    (Longitude BETWEEN (4.88227 - 40/42.5) AND (4.88227 + 40/42.5))
    )
HAVING distance < 40 ORDER BY distance
```

...and this comes back as

```
Showing rows 0 - 24 (1855 total, Query took 0.0288 seconds.)
```

Then another version that actually gives the "distance" back (as we want to sort by that, and only include the closest);

```
SELECT ID,st_distance_sphere(POINT(4.88227,52.35462), point_test) / 1000 AS distance FROM glinks_Links WHERE ( ((Latitude BETWEEN (52.35462 - 40/69.0) AND (52.35462 + 40/69.0)) ) AND (Longitude BETWEEN (4.88227 - 40/42.5) AND (4.88227 + 40/42.5)) ) HAVING DISTANCE < 100 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

Gives:

```
Showing rows 0 - 99 (100 total, Query took 0.0237 seconds.)
```

Then what seems to be the best:

```
SELECT * 
FROM glinks_Links
where st_distance_sphere(POINT(4.88227,52.35462), point_test)/1000 <= 100
```

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (3439 total, Query took 0.0015 seconds.)

The issue with that though - is that it doesn't provide me with the distance! What I want to do is query and grab the 100 closest. Is there a way I can do this, without compramising on the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure you have proper composite index  on

```
 create index  my_idx ON  glinks_Links (Latitude, Longitude, ID)
```

And  you don't  need  unuseful  ()  for where condition  (using AND)

```
SELECT ID,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.35462) ) * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Longitude ) - radians(4.88227) ) + sin( radians(52.35462) ) 
    * sin( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM glinks_Links
WHERE Latitude BETWEEN (52.35462 - 40/69.0) AND (52.35462 + 40/69.0)
AND Longitude BETWEEN (4.88227 - 40/42.5) AND (4.88227 + 40/42.5)
HAVING distance < 40 
ORDER BY distance
```

for the second version

```
  SELECT ID, st_distance_sphere(POINT(4.88227,52.35462), point_test) / 1000 AS distance 
  FROM glinks_Links 
  WHERE Latitude BETWEEN (52.35462 - 40/69.0) AND (52.35462 + 40/69.0)
  AND  Longitude BETWEEN (4.88227 - 40/42.5) AND (4.88227 + 40/42.5)
  HAVING DISTANCE < 100 
  ORDER BY distance 
  LIMIT 100
```

you should use a composite index on

```
 create index  myidx ON glinks_Links (Latitude, Longitude, point_test, ID )
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to get away from that query :) We are moving over to SPATIAL fields (the `point_test` column, which is a **POINT**). The 3rd query I have is fast, but I don't have a way to sort it based on the smallest distance first )

Comment: thanks, but `table  glinks_Links columns (Latitude, Longitude, point_test, ID )` gives me an error? `You have an error near "table glinks_Links columns (Latitude, Longitude, point_test, ID)" at line 1`

Comment: for better performance you need  composite redundant index  (index with columns in where and in select for use the index info only and avoid table access).  answer  updated  with right create index sintax  too

Comment: Thanks - its getting there. I'll accept, but going to play with it a bit more tomorrow. I'm sure I can squeeze a bit more speed out of it (the whole point of moving to the SPATAIL fields is to try and get it at least 50% faster, but its only fractionally faster now)